# android gradle task for assembling apk

Tags: android, gradle, apk

Android: what is the gradle task creating apk file? I like to add some files.

```
createApk {
    from ("/path/foo") {
       include "conf/*.xml"
    }
}
```

I do not want these file to be under assets.

UPDATE

---

```
Detailed task information for packageDebug

Path
     :app:packageDebug

Type
     PackageApplication (com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication)
```

Is there a way to config packageDebug task?

```
android {
   packageDebug {

       packagedJars.add(file("/path/foo.jar"))
    }
}
```

or outside of android

```
 packageDebug {

       packagedJars.add(file("/path/foo.jar"))
    }
```

Error:

```
 Could not find method packageDebug() for arguments 
 [build_5mzln4dsvn1rw7q419jieg6iv$_run_closure2$_closure9@11943ec2]
 on object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.
```

Comment: Use assets or resources. Do not randomly put files inside of an APK in arbitrary locations.

Comment: How to access resources(java-style, not android resources)? Thanks.